# Which version control package do you suggest for this purpose

Tags: svn, version-control

We have super computers that researchers/scientists run simulations and tests on. We would like them to be able to easily check their code and results into a version control system.

The first thing that came to mind was Subversion, but I have heard of others such as Bazzar, Mercurial and Git.

Which would you recommend, based on the following:

- Ease of installation and maintenance
- Quality of the API
- Other features you can think of

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041119/

Comment: Thanks, for some reason I didn't see that.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want an answer that is relevent to your application or are you just after pros and cons?

I think that the most interesting parts of your problem will not be affected by the exact version control tool but how you standardise the approach to managing code and results and your method for compiling, deploying and running the code then gathering and storing the results. This will make all the difference.

I'd only suggest mercurial since it's easy to use.

Comment: Yes agreed, at the moment I am playing around with SVN, if that goes well might stick with that, but you are right about the actual choice not being the most important thing but managing the user's workflow for the whole process.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what your needs are. What is the workflow, what do you expect from the SCM?

SVN is a centralized SCM with only one repository, while others lik Git and Mercurial are decentralized.